# Make non-published "petitions" inaccessible by url

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a petition model with a BooleanField called "published" and by default it is set to false.

```
class Petition(models.Model):
  # Added on creation
  target = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
  body = models.TextField()
  goal = models.IntegerField()

  # Added after form creation
  letter = models.TextField(null=True)
  published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  featured_image = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
  end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

  # Not User Submitted
  is_victory = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.title

  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("petitions:detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

On the petition index page I know I can filter by only published petitions and non-published petitions will not show. But right now non-published petitions are still accessible if you entered the url path in manually. How can I get it to show a "petition doesn't exist" message for petitions that have not been published.

Comment: Maybe you should show the code for the relevant view?

Answer (score 0):

In your petitions detail view, add a line that checks if the petition is published and returns a "petition doesn't exist" template if it doesn't:

```
if petition.published != true:  # You can simplify to 'if not petition.published:'
    return render(request, 'petition_doesnt_exist.html')
```

And continue on with the rest of your view logic otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In the view, raise 404 when is not published.

```
from django.http import Http404

def view(request, ...):
    if petition.published != true:
        raise Http404()
```